# How to make a field depend on the value of another field in Kentico form builder

Tags: kentico

I'm creating a contact form which should allow the user to enter *either* phone or email or both. My conditions would be something like:

`Email.value != "" || Phone.value != ""`

I just have no idea how to write this as a K# macro rule in the Forms -> Form Builder -> Field Validation -> General Condition editor. Is it even possible to get the value of other fields? All the predefined rules are completely unrelated to the current form data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is correct. The problem is that the validation happens only for non-empty fields. If you have any required field in your form, put the condition there and then style the validation, or create dummy required field for same purpose. Similar as here:

http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/tweaking-kentico-(1)-hidden-required-fields

Comment: Damn that's awkward. Maybe I could do something like setting a default value of a single space character to give it a value so it can be validated or something cheeky like that? I'll have a play, thanks.

Comment: The issue is any validation added to a field that is not marked as Required makes mandatory field from it, so it doesn't apply validation for empty fields. That dummy field it's not that bad workaround since it could be just in the alternative form so it has no actual database representation, so it's there just for your validation purposes.

Comment: Alright, if I go down this route, how could I make the errors still appear underneath the relevant fields rather than all under the required field?

Comment: Same way it's described in that link. More over, you can have completely custom layout of your form to move with either lables, fields or validation messages.

Comment: here is very simple example -> http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/how-to-check-if-two-fields-contain-same-value

Answer (score 0):

First of all use Forms -> Fields - it gives you much more options. Form builder is for content editors and covers simple scenarios.

Under Fields tab navigate fields that other fields depend on and check Has depending field. Now switch to depending field, check Depends on another field and enter some macro into visibility or enable condition.

Also it should be enough to enter `Email` vs. `Email.value`

Comment: I don't want to control the visibility or enabled properties of the fields though as I want the user to be able to enter both if they wish. I only want to setup the validation so that it's enough for the user to either either or both fields.